# mono for android application

Tags: android-emulator

I am working on gaming application in mono android. I want sample code for background image scrolling vertically from top to bottom. I have a code but it is not working properly.So plz somebody help me.

```
    mBGFarMoveY = mBGFarMoveY + 3;
    int newFarY = mBackgroundImageFar.Height + (+ mBGFarMoveY);
    if (newFarY <= 0) 
    {
    mBGFarMoveY = 0;
    canvas.DrawBitmap (mBackgroundImageFar,0,mBGFarMoveY,null);
    } 
    else
    {
    canvas.DrawBitmap (mBackgroundImageFar,0,mBGFarMoveY,null);
    canvas.DrawBitmap (mBackgroundImageFar,0, newFarY, null);
    }
```

Thanks&Regard's,
Chakradhar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you see and what do you expect?  There are several issues with your code as far as I can see.

1. The position is not calculated based upon time, so scrolling will
   be jumpy.
2. The overlap code doesn't look too great  and blits a lot out of bounds.  I'm not sure
   what 'canvas' is, but if it is the one from android.graphics, you
   can specify the source and destination rectangles to blit rather
   than just the 'y' position.

so something like (untested and I've not written code for this platform before but you should get the idea):

```
y = (time_seconds * pixels_per_second);
y = y % image.Height; // wrap
src_rect.left = 0;
src_rect.right = image.Width - 1;
src_rect.top = y;
src_rect.bottom = image.Height - 1;

dst_rect.left = 0;
dst_rect.right = image.Width - 1;
dst_rect.top = 0;
dst_rect.bottom = image.Height - 1;

if (y == 0) {
    canvas.DrawBitmap(image, src_rect, dst_rect, null);
}
else {
    dst_rect.bottom = src_rect.height() - 1;
    canvas.DrawBitmap(image, src_rect, dst_rect, null);

    src_rect.top = 0;
    src_rect.bottom = y - 1;
    dst_rect.top = dst_rect.bottom + 1;
    dst_rect.bottom = image.Height - 1;

    canvas.DrawBitmap(image, src_rect, dst_rect, null);
}
```